# Как определить на какой страница edit или show находиться пользователь в react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Для страниц show и edit у меня один компонент но проблема в том что я не знаю как можно определить что за страница выбрана, как это можно сделать? В vue-router мы можем давать названия роутам, а возможно както в react-router так делать?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import List from './Post/List';
import Single from './Post/Single';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
                    <Route
                        path="/posts"
                        render={({ match: { path } }) => (
                            <>
                                <Route path={`${path}/`} component={List} exact />
                                <Route path={`${path}/show/:id`} name="show" component={Single} />
                                <Route path={`${path}/edit/:id`} name="edit" component={Single} />
                            </>
                        )}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Single.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Single extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { page: '' };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.page}</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Single;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сам недавно искал и не нашел. 
самые распостраненные способы - это определять маршру через объект `history`, либо в компонент передавайте текущие данные роутера через **props** (вместо `component={Single}` пишите `render={() => <Single currentPath="show/edit" />}`;)